# Preservation of determinants mod some ideal

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, determinant, matrix-equations

Given a matrix with entries drawn from some field or commutative ring, what are the conditions for the determinant to be preserved mod some ideal? For a concrete example, I am thinking of matrices with entries drawn from $\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$. I would appreciate any direction on this: this feels like a common question, but I am having trouble finding resources. Thanks!

Comment: what are you talking about???? preserved???

Comment: I wondering if I take a matrix with entries drawn from a commutative ring or field, say R, and reduce the entries mod some ideal I, will the determinant of the second matrix be the same as the determinant of the first mod I?

Comment: yes. A determinant is a polynomial, the sum of a bunch of products. If $a \equiv b$ and $c \equiv d,$ then $a + c \equiv b + d$ and $ac \equiv bd.$

Comment: Ah, okay. Thanks for the quick solution!

Comment: To expand on Will's comment, the determinant will be "preserved" by any ring homomorphism.